# Block.number - how to fetch it correctly

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I want to get the current block number of all blocks.
If I run return block.number it only returns me the number of blocks since the last deploy.

Why is it like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the Remix VM environment.

[image]

This environment is in memory and Remix only generates new blocks when someone deploys something or sends a transaction. Therefore you are getting the latest generated block when you deployed the contract

to have what you want you can download and start [Ganache](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/) and then connect Ganache to remix (limitation: i think you will not be able to debug transactions)

[image]

Remember to disable "auto mine" in Ganache, otherwise, it will work as Remix did

[image]

Update: there is also another way (commands using the console) to change the time and this will generate empty new blocks. but this is another question :D